# Xamarin.Android CertificateFactory.GetInstance("X.509").GenerateCertificate with MemoryStream result to "inStream is empty"

Tags: xamarin.android, base64, certificate, memorystream, generate

There is my context: We have Xamarin.Forms App that receive a certificate from the server in Base64 String with \n\r. I want to put this certificate in KeyStore so I'm doing this code :

```
        var ks = KeyStore.GetInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        ks.Load(null);

        if (ks.ContainsAlias(RSAStrings.ServerCertificateName))
        {
            ks.DeleteEntry(RSAStrings.ServerCertificateName);
        }

        var cerBase64 = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" + Environment.NewLine + cer + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" + Environment.NewLine;
        var cerBytes = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cerBase64);
        var memStream = new MemoryStream(cerBytes);
        this.serverCertificate = CertificateFactory.GetInstance("X.509").GenerateCertificate(memStream);
        ks.SetCertificateEntry(RSAStrings.ServerCertificateName, this.serverCertificate);
```

When GenerateCertificate, I got error "inStream is empty", but my MemoryStream contains all bytes, I can see it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you !

Comment: Did you try to use   `MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(cerBytes);`,not use `ByteArrayInputStream` ?

Comment: Hello Leo, yes i start with MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(certBytes); but it was not working

Comment: It's weird,the codes seem to be correct.Could cerBytes be obtained correctly ?

Comment: Yes, I was able to see all bytes.

Comment: Anyway, I create a workaround by saving the certificate in an encrypted file and by using X509Certificate2 instead of put it in the store.